# Diophantine Equation with Square Root

Tags: modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, square-numbers, congruence-relations

I want to resolve the diophantine equation:

$\sqrt{x^2+5x+12} ≡ x-2\pmod 5$

I have thought 2 ways:

1.

$(\sqrt{x^2+5x+12})^2 ≡ (x-2)^2\pmod 5$

$ x^2+5x+12 ≡ x^2 -4x+4\pmod 5$

$ 9x+8 ≡  0\pmod 5$

$ 4x+3 ≡  0\pmod 5$

$ 4x+3 = 5y$

$ 4x-5y = -3$

I resolve:

$x=5n+3$, 
n
∈
Z

$y=4n+3$, 
n
∈
Z

2.

$\sqrt{x^2+5x+12} ≡ x-2\pmod 5$

$\sqrt{x^2+5x+12} = x-2 + 5y$

$(\sqrt{x^2+5x+12})^2 = (x-2 + 5y)^2$

$x^2+5x+12 = 10xy+x^2-4x-20y+25y^2+4$

$25y^2+10xy-9x-20y-8 = 0$ and resolve that diophantine equation.

My questions are: Are both procedures valid? If so, does the development of each procedure preserve the value of the initial x and y unknowns?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by $x-2_5$? That we work in the finite field $\Bbb F_5$? But then $5x$ should be $0$.

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde, It's a congruence modulo 5. It's works en $Z_5$

Comment: It will be a lot clearer if you put `\pmod 5`, i.e., $\pmod 5$, at the end of your congruences instead of the subscript.

Comment: Again, then $x^2+5x+12$ is just $x^2+2$.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde, is that correct even within a square root?

Comment: $x = 3 \mod 5$ is the only solution

Comment: Yes, since $\Bbb F_5$ is a field, we can write all congruences modulo $5$ as equations and view all coefficients in $\Bbb F_5$.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde, and that preserves the initial x and y solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Writing the congruence as an equation in the field $\Bbb F_5$ we obtain
$$
x^2+5x+12=(x-2)^2=x^2-4x+4,
$$
which gives $4x=2$. In $\Bbb F_5$ this has the unique solution $2^{-1}=3$, because $2\cdot 3=6=1$, so that $3$ is the inverse of $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Then I have done:

$\sqrt{x^2+5x+12} ≡ x-2\pmod 5$

$\sqrt{x^2+2} ≡ x-2\pmod 5$

$\sqrt{x^2+2} = x-2+5y$

$x^2+2 = (x-2+5y)^2$ and that equation more recient dont have solutions and $\sqrt{x^2+5x+12} ≡ x-2\pmod 5$ has solutions, Why?

Thanks

Comment: You are passing to integers by adding $5y$. Then you also have to add $5x$ again under the square root. If you stay with $\Bbb Z_5$ you have $x^2+2=(x-2)^2$, which has a solution in $\Bbb Z_5$, namely $x=3$.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde, Although in this equation adding 5x under the square root works and the resulting equation has a solution, it is not the same as the original equation. I have tried adding Nx (N is the modulus) in other square root equations and in some cases they have no solutions. What is the property you use when you add 5x under the square root? Thank you

Comment: What is the property I use? It is the question over which ring or field we solve an equation. Over $\Bbb Z$ or over $\Bbb Z/p$? This is a difference. $x^2+2=(x-2)^2$ has no solution over $\Bbb Z$, but has a solution over $\Bbb Z/5$. We want to solve your equation over $\Bbb Z/5$, right? (Note: $x\equiv y\bmod 5$ if and only if $x=y$ in $\Bbb Z/5$).

Comment: @Dietrich Burde, I say: $\sqrt{x^2+5x+12} ≡ x-2\pmod 5$  --> $\sqrt{x^2+2} ≡ x-2\pmod 5$ --> $\sqrt{x^2+5x+2} = x-2 +5y $ . In this case works, although others cases no
.  What is the reason? Thanks

Comment: I know:  $f≡g (mod5)$ --> $f=g+5y$, independent of f and g